What is the difference between order of precedence and order of evaluation in C?
I have a specific example in mind.
x = a +++ b;

This is evaluated as a++ not ++b. But I don't understand if this is due to order of precedence of postfix being higher than prefix, or due to order of evaluation being right-to-left.
What is the difference between these two terms?

The grammar says tokens are created as large as possible. In your expression the tokens are x, =, a. ++ (token + would be "valid", but ++ is "more valid"), +, b, and ;. No "order of precedence" or "order of evaluation" required." See C11 6.4p4

Related: the Maximal Munch Rule as seen here.

Operator precedence and associativity affect parsing, not tokenization. They are not relevant here. Operand evaluation order affects code generation. That's even further removed and thus even less relevant.

The C and C++ compilers process tokens eagerly and will split the expression based on the longest possible valid tokens it can find. It is defined by C standard

C11 Standard, Section 6.4, Paragraph 4
If a ‘token’ can be formed by concatenating characters to form a valid
keyword, identifier, constant, string literal, punctuator, or other
character, then the largest possible ‘token’ should be selected.


To answer the question in the title: precedence determines the grouping of operators with their operands, but it does not determine the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.
Given the expression
a + b * c

* has higher precedence than + so the parse tree is
            +
           / \
          a   *
             / \
            b   c

but each of a, b, and c can be evaluated in any order.
The only operators that force left-to-right evaluation are &&, ||, ?:, and the comma operator (which is not the same thing as the comma separating function arguments).
As others have pointed out, the result you're seeing is determined by tokenization rules, not operator precedence or evaluation order.
